# Tkinter name widgets in a loop

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I am currently creating a 'grid' of textboxes in Tkinter, in order to emulate a golf scorecard system. I am currently using the code below to create this grid. As I am storing the entries into these textboxes into a Microsoft Access database, how can I use the .get() function to retrieve the values from individual text boxes if the widgets created do not have unique names. I don't really want to create 105 text boxes manually, even though I know that would work. Any help is appreciated.

```
        for x in range(1, 22):
            for y in range(4, 9):
                e  = tk.Text(self,
                             height=1,
                             width=3)

                e.grid(column=x,
                       row=y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd use a dictionary as it would allow you to reference the widgets according to their grid position. You could do this like so:

```
text_widgets = {}
for x in range(1, 22):
    for y in range(4, 9):
        e  = tk.Text(self,
                     height=1,
                     width=3)

        e.grid(column=x,
               row=y)

        text_widgets[(x, y)] = e
```

This allows you to access the widgets positionally at a later time - so, if you wanted the value of the widget in column 10, row 7 you could access it by using:

```
text_widgets[(10, 7)].get('1.0', 'end-1c')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list to hold the entry values and after a loop to read them.This is what I usually do.

Try:

```
entries_list = []
for x in range(1, 22):
            for y in range(4, 9):
                e  = tk.Text(self,
                             height=1,
                             width=3)

                e.grid(column=x,
                       row=y)
                entries_list.append(e)
```

and after:

```
for x in entries_list:
    x.get(1.0, END)
```

Comment: Technically, text widget indexes are not floating point numbers. They are strings of the form `"<line>.<character>"`. `1.0` is harmless, but you'll get different results than you expect with `1.10`, for example.